# Fetch the current page name in LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I created some pages with a hierarchy like Home(with child pages), About US, Contact How can I fetch the current page in lwc template?

Are there ways to fetch all the available pages in the community using the same template? Or is there any API object for the page name I can pass?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question but try to post it on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. Community pages are weird. The builder is not identical to normal app builder (for example doesn't do component visibility), they don't get saved as "normal" Lightning Pages (FlexiPages). And you deploy them as either part JSON, part binary mess of SiteDotCom or as readable but complex Experience Bundle. I don't think you can query them, sorry. Have you seen https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5 ?

Comment: Thanks for the details. I've posted in the given link. It's actually hard to find simple things in the documentation. I ll check the metadataAPI. Thanks.